# When or Why to use a "SET DEFINE OFF" in Oracle Database

Tags: oracle, sqlplus

I'm watching a Script in Oracle and I see something I don't recognize

```
REM INSERTING into database1."Users"
 SET DEFINE OFF;
Insert into database1."Users" ("id","right") values ('1','R');
```

I'm looking for documentation about "set define off" and it's literally writing "disable the parsing of commands to replace substitution variable with their values"

I don't really understand what they want to say.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: turns off prompting substitution variables. so you are not prompted to insert a value when it sees your substitution variable I believe the default is &.

Comment: This is a setting for the SQL _client_, not the database itself. And thus it's documented in the SQL*Plus manual: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e16604/ch_twelve040.htm#SQPUG073

Answer (score 164, accepted):

By default, SQL Plus treats '&' as a special character that begins a substitution string.  This can cause problems when running scripts that happen to include '&' for other reasons:

```
SQL> insert into customers (customer_name) values ('Marks & Spencers Ltd');
Enter value for spencers: 
old   1: insert into customers (customer_name) values ('Marks & Spencers Ltd')
new   1: insert into customers (customer_name) values ('Marks  Ltd')

1 row created.

SQL> select customer_name from customers;

CUSTOMER_NAME
------------------------------
Marks  Ltd
```

If you know your script includes (or may include) data containing '&' characters, and you do not want the substitution behaviour as above, then use `set define off` to switch off the behaviour while running the script:

```
SQL> set define off
SQL> insert into customers (customer_name) values ('Marks & Spencers Ltd');

1 row created.

SQL> select customer_name from customers;

CUSTOMER_NAME
------------------------------
Marks & Spencers Ltd
```

You might want to add `set define on` at the end of the script to restore the default behaviour.

Answer (score 21):

Here is the example:

```
SQL> set define off;
SQL> select * from dual where dummy='&var';

no rows selected

SQL> set define on
SQL> /
Enter value for var: X
old   1: select * from dual where dummy='&var'
new   1: select * from dual where dummy='X'

D
-
X
```

With `set define off`, it took a row with `&var` value, prompted a user to enter a value for it and replaced `&var` with the entered value (in this case, `X`).