# Storing string containing characters like single, ampersand qoutes in a variable

Tags: string, oracle, plsql, clob

My procedure will be receiving string (email body message) as a input parameter which will be assigned to a variable. it can contain characters like single quotes and ampersand. How can I handle this situation and assign the string as is to a clob variable.

```
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON

DECLARE

email_body CLOB;

BEGIN

email_body:=to_clob('Hel's Message');

DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(length(email_body));

EXCEPTION
WHEN OTHERS THEN
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUt_LINE(SQLCODE||' '||SQLERRM);

END;
```

> Error:
>
> ORA-06550: line 7, column 22: PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "S"
>   when expecting one of the following:

Comment: If your procedure gets the string as an input parameter, you don't have to perform any special action at all - all quoting / escaping will be performed by the calling code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try the following:

```
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON
/* disable variable substitution */
SET DEFINE OFF 

DECLARE
email_body CLOB;
BEGIN
email_body:=to_clob(q'[Hel's M&ssage]'); /* Q operator to avoid issues with quotes */

    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(length(email_body));

EXCEPTION
    WHEN OTHERS THEN
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUt_LINE(SQLCODE||' '||SQLERRM);
END;
/
```

Here I use [SET DEFINE OFF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34332639/when-or-why-to-use-a-set-define-off-in-oracle-database) to prevent variable substitution and the Oracle [Q quote operator](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/sql_elements003.htm#i42617) to handle strings with quotes.