# Ignore bind variables in DELETE statements Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle11g, bind-variables

I'm running hundreds of `SQL DELETE` statements in a single go within a `BEGIN - END` block in Oracle DB. I need to ignore the bind variables to treat the complete text as values.

Using `Set define off` doesn't help as it says

> BIND variable not declared

Any help on this to run all the delete statements without bind variable errors. A portion of SQL is below.

```
SET DEFINE OFF       
BEGIN       
    DELETE FROM CLOOKUP WHERE PKID='294569246' AND VALUE ='Myco :Zear';       
    DELETE FROM CLOOKUP WHERE PKID='245342523' AND VALUE ='Asta :Ochra';    
    DELETE FROM CLOOKUP WHERE PKID='947893478' AND VALUE ='Isomene';    
    DELETE FROM CLOOKUP WHERE PKID='947893478' AND VALUE ='T-Acid & Methyl';        
END;
```

Comment: Refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43876365/why-is-set-define-off-not-working-for-the-colon-character

Comment: Which tool do you use to run that PL/SQL block? I tried it in SQL*Plus as well as SQL Developer - no problem whatsoever. `SET DEFINE OFF` took care about both colon and ampersand.