# How to insert regex with special characters like “&,?.@:;” in oracle database?

Tags: sql, regex, oracle

I have a regex value that I want to insert in oracle database table column but I have some problems that the value doesn't inserted correctly in the database
this is the value that I want to insert :

```
INSERT INTO valid_value VALUES (9, 14, 'REGEX[[A-Z.,-\s]+(,\s[A-Za-z.,-\s]+)?]', 1);
```

the result of this insert is :

```
valid_value 
+--------------------------------------+
REGEX[[A-Z.,-\s]+(,\s[A-Za-z.,-\s]+)]
```

I lose the "?" character can some one help me on this how to insert regex value in a table column.

I start the script using a batch file

```
set DB_CREATE_ROOT="%~dp0"
set SQL_INIT_CONF_DIR=%DB_CREATE_ROOT%\Scripts\configuration\
for /r %SQL_INIT_CONF_DIR% %%F in (*init.sql) do (


    ECHO %DATE% %TIME%  "%%F" >> %LOG_NAME%
    sqlplus -L Test_APP/welkom@//localhost:1521/xe @"%%F" >> %LOG_NAME% 2>&1
)
```

thanks in advance

Comment: Works fine for me, in SQL\*Plus and SQL Developer. Which client are you using? It woulds like maybe the client is interpreting the question mark?

Comment: None of those characters have a special meaning in the context of SQL, as a simple `SELECT 'REGEX[[A-Z.,-\s]+(,\s[A-Za-z.,-\s]+)?]' FROM DUAL;` illustrates. What exact problem are you facing?

Comment: it's work fine in sqldevlopper but when I run the script using sqlplus it's not work

Comment: It works for me in SQL*Plus. How **exactly** is it not working?

Comment: it insert this value REGEX[[A-Z.,-\s]+(,\s[A-Za-z.,-\s]+)]  instead of REGEX[[A-Z.,-\s]+(,\s[A-Za-z.,-\s]+)?]  I lose *?* character

Comment: What kind of script - just a .sql you run from SQL\*Plus? And how are you querying it? What happens if you just run that insert manually directly from the SQL\*Plus prompt, and then query the table the same way?

Comment: Can you please edit the question and copy+past the exact SQL*Plus session, including both `INSERT` and a subsequent `SELECT`?

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález i update my question

Comment: I think it won't fail if you just execute the statement alone. You have a complex data load process and I don't think there's enough information to determine that `?` alone is the point of failure. I suggest you grab a copy of everything and start removing steps until the issue gets fixed or you have a small self-contained example to share. BTW, here's a little [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/283d2/1);

Comment: I don't see how to reproduce what you are seeing; maybe there's something in your environment or in the .sql script that causing this, but nothing obvious jumps out. (Having `set define ?` won't make a difference here, for instance.)

Comment: it's work when I use the chr() function with ascii code for "?" thanks guys

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `CHR` function for each of the special characters if you find difficulties with direct inserts.

Thanks

Comment: Yes the chr solve the problem it's work with INSERT INTO valid_value VALUES (9, 14, 'REGEX[[A-Z-\s]+(,\s[A-Za-z-\s]+)'||chr(63)||']', 1);  thx

Comment: Welcome to S.O!

Answer (score 2):

For the records, none of the characters mentioned have a special meaning inside SQL strings thus they don't need any special treatment:

```
SQL> SELECT '&,?.@:;' AS are_we_special
  2  FROM DUAL;

ARE_WE_
-------
&,?.@:;
```

([online demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/283d2/1))

... being `&` the only possible exception ([“SET DEFINE OFF” in Oracle Database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34332639/when-or-why-to-use-a-set-define-off-in-oracle-database)) and only in the context of SQL*Plus and SQL Developer—in which case you'd be getting a *Enter value for xxxxx* prompt.

Whatever problem the OP had, `CHR()` is just a workaround for his specific undisclosed issue.

Comment: Not in SQL; but `&` is the default substitution character in those clients. Trivial to avoid that one being a problem with `set deifne off`, of course, and doesn't matter anyway when followed by punctuation as in your demo. (And `set define ?` wouldn't cause the OP's problem for the same reason.)

Comment: @AlexPoole I've tried to improve my answer. I don't have Oracle here to verify stuff so I hope I didn't make any mistake.

Answer (score 0):

This may help you

```
   INSERT INTO valid_value VALUES (9, 14, 'REGEX[[A-Z.,-\s]+(,\s[A-Za-z.,-\s]+)'?']', 1);
```

Comment: This throws "ORA-00911: invalid character" in SQL\*Plus, and SQL Developer seems to think the question mark is a bind placeholder and errors with "Missing IN or OUT parameter".

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
INSERT INTO valid_value VALUES (9, 14, 'REGEX[[A-Z.,-\s]+(,\s[A-Za-z.,-\s]+) ?]', 1);
```

See demo:

In SQLPLUS:

```
SQL> /

COL1                                            
---------------------------------------------
REGEX[[A-Z.,-\s]+(,\s[A-Za-z.,-\s]+) ?]
```

Now question is which client you are using. In SQLPLUS, its working as shown above.

Comment: This insert this value "REGEX[[A-Z.,-\s]+(,\s[A-Za-z.,-\s]+)\]"

Comment: Why would this make a difference to a string literal (other than modifying the intended value)? The regex isn't being applied to anything yet?

Comment: Just I want to store the regex as a string value the problem is each time lose the "?" character

Comment: @ErrabiAyoub Did you use what i posted. I mean i put a space before `?` . Its not the same as in your question

Comment: I will try to add space

Comment: @ErrabiAyoub You just copy and paste and execute what i posted, It should work for you,

Comment: Since when do spaces have any special meaning in SQL? It shouldn't make any difference from Oracle perspective and it'll break the regexp.

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález In `Oracle` Special characters either needed to be escaped or should be with a space if you want to store it. You can try the demo posted. I hope regex will also not be broken as it wont consider the space. See and try the demo i posted and let me know if its not working for you

Comment: Even accepting that `?` is a special character, if you add a space the space gets stored. Try `SELECT DUMP('?'), DUMP(' ?') FROM DUAL;`.

Comment: still ignore ? even I add space  the result of SELECT DUMP('?'), DUMP(' ?') FROM DUAL   is  :    Typ=96 Len=1: 63 Typ=96 Len=2: 32,63

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález yes,,i knw space would be there but i really wanted to see if this works with OP since i dont know the client he is using plus simply executing `REGEX[[A-Z.,-\s]+(,\s[A-Za-z.,-\s]+) ?]` in oracle will throw error

Comment: it's work when I use the chr() function with ascii code for "?" thanks guys