# SQL - LPX-00242: invalid use of ampersand ('&') character (use &amp;)

Tags: sql, oracle, xmltype

I'm trying to run the below sql query.

```
SELECT sr.resultid, xt2.*
FROM   RESULTS sr,
       XMLTABLE('/extraInfo/resultsViewData'
           PASSING XMLType(sr.extrainfo)
           COLUMNS 
               docketNumber    VARCHAR2(35)  PATH 'docketNumber',
               dateFiled       VARCHAR2(35)  PATH 'dateFiled',
               nosDescription  VARCHAR2(70)  PATH 'nosDescription',
               courtname       VARCHAR2(100) PATH 'courtname',
               chapter         VARCHAR2(35)  PATH 'chapter'
       ) xt2 
WHERE  sr.profileId = '7dd76222';
```

NOTE: `sr.extrainfo` has the value

```
'<extraInfo><resultsViewData><courtname>FL Circuit &amp; County - Santa Rosa</courtname></resultsViewData></extraInfo>'
```

Even though I use `'& amp ;'` instead of `'&'`, I still get the below error,

```
ORA-31011: XML parsing failed
ORA-19213: error occurred in XML processing at lines 1
LPX-00242: invalid use of ampersand ('&') character (use &amp;)
ORA-06512: at "SYS.XMLTYPE", line 272
ORA-06512: at line 1
31011. 00000 -  "XML parsing failed"
*Cause:    XML parser returned an error while trying to parse the document.
*Action:   Check if the document to be parsed is valid.
```

Sometimes I even get the error,

```
LPX-00242: invalid use of ampersand ('&') character (use &amp;amp;)
```

Is there any way to overcome this issue?

Comment: Could it be similar to this? https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=100:11:::NO::P11_QUESTION_ID:9536876300346964655

Comment: Unable to replicate this [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=aef73f0a8b8d68fd5b76a233b0dda474). Please can you [edit] your question with a [MRE] that is complete enough that we can execute it and produces the error?

Comment: @MT0 The XML used in my project is way bigger. I just used a smaller xml for simplicity hence the issue isn't getting reproduced. I am now using '&' instead of '&amp;' in extrainfo and I'm using  PASSING XMLType(DBMS_XMLGEN.CONVERT(sr.extrainfo)) since I read somewhere that DBMS_XMLGEN.CONVERT can be used to escape &. But I'm getting the error 'LPX-00210: expected '<' instead of 't'. Same error appears in fiddler as well.

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
set define off;
```

Then execute your query;

If you want more info on what `set define off;` does: [When or Why to use a "SET DEFINE OFF" in Oracle Database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34332639/when-or-why-to-use-a-set-define-off-in-oracle-database/34333860)

Comment: If this is SQL\*Plus with `define` on and set to the default `&` character, surely it wouldn't pass an `&` character to the database? I would expect it to ask for a value for `amp`.

Comment: Yes. With define on when you try to execute the query, it will ask you to pass the value for amp.

Comment: So seems like the issue can't be due to the substitution variable setting.

Answer (score 0):

I am not able to reproduce your issue at first place.

But still if you are getting the issue then try to use `dbms_xmlgen.convert` to convert your string as following:

```
'<extraInfo><resultsViewData><courtname>'
|| dbms_xmlgen.convert('FL Circuit & County - Santa Rosa')
|| '</courtname></resultsViewData></extraInfo>'
```

[db<>fiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=09da7e147f05d41edcf2ee4ea209e560)

Cheers!!

Comment: I tried this but I'm getting "LPX-00210: expected '<' instead of '&' " error.

Comment: It means your XML is not valid. Are you trying with the string which is shown in the question? or any other string? for string given in the question, It is working perfectly fine as can be seen from DB fiddle

Comment: PASSING XMLType(DBMS_XMLGEN.CONVERT(sr.extrainfo))  causes the above error I mentioned

Comment: I'm using a bigger XML and not the one that I've mentioned here. I wont be able to use dbms_xmlgen.convert for a particular portion within the XML since its large and large number of XMLs are already stored in DB. So '&' can appear anywhere. Hence I tired to use dbms_xmlgen.convert in PASSING XMLType() but I'm getting the error that I mentioned

Comment: I feel that the XML is valid because even in the fiddler if you change it to PASSING XMLType(DBMS_XMLGEN.CONVERT(sr.extrainfo)), LPX-00210: expected '<' instead of 't'  occurs