# ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended? Enter Bind Variables?

Tags: sql, oracle

I am attempting to write out in my SQL commands for Oracle Apex 5, and I cannot see why I'm getting an error. Also, a popup window appears once I submit asking to `'Enter Bind Variables'` for '`:NEW'`? Isn't it already declared?

```
drop table tmpcapacityguide cascade constraints;
drop table tmpcaravanpark cascade constraints;

create table tmpcaravanpark as select * from Caravan_park;
create table tmpcapacityguide 
(mincap   number(3),
 maxcap   number(3));

insert into tmpcapacityguide values(30, 150);

CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER "PARK_CAPACITY_CHECK" 
before insert or update of capacity
on Caravan_park
for each row
when (:new.capacity < 30) DECLARE
mincapacity integer;
maxcapacity integer;

begin
select mincap, maxcap
into mincapacity, maxcapacity
from tmpcapacityguide
where capacity = :new.capacity;
if (new.capacity < mincapacity)
then raise_application_error(-20601, 'Capacity must be between 30 and 150');
end if;
end;
```

Comment: `tmpcapacityguide` has no column called `capacity`.

Comment: I've added tmpcaravanpark

Comment: What tool are your using to run the the script?

Comment: I have ran it as a script and have now got the following error: PL/SQL: ORA-00904: "CAPACITY": invalid identifier

Answer (score 0):

Try using slashes, and name of trigger after last end, and also You do not need ":" sign before new variable in IF statement:

```
drop table tmpcapacityguide cascade constraints;
drop table tmpcaravanpark cascade constraints;

create table tmpcaravanpark as select * from Caravan_park;
create table tmpcapacityguide  (mincap   number(3), maxcap   number(3));
/
insert into tmpcapacityguide values(30, 150);
/
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER PARK_CAPACITY_CHECK 
    before insert or update of capacity on caravan_park
    for each row
    when (new.capacity < 30) 
declare
    mincapacity integer;
    maxcapacity integer;
begin
    select mincap, maxcap
    into mincapacity, maxcapacity
    from tmpcapacityguide
    where capacity = :new.capacity;

    if (new.capacity < mincapacity)
    then 
        raise_application_error(-20601, 'Capacity must be between 30 and 150');
    end if;
end PARK_CAPACITY_CHECK;
/
```

Also, You should execute it as a script, not statement in SQL Developer. This can be done by pressing `F9`, not `F5`, as sstated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12166046/creating-a-trigger-in-oracle-express).

**EDIT:**

As for Your ORA-00904 error, You still do not have capacity column in Your tmpcapacityguide table. And You try to use it here:

```
select mincap, maxcap
into mincapacity, maxcapacity
from tmpcapacityguide
where capacity = :new.capacity;
```

Comment: Tried your suggestions, errors still persist. I don't understand why I'm getting a popup window asking me to enter bind variables for :NEW isnt it already declared?

Comment: Reaserched this a litte bit, and added comment below example. Also, added trailing slash, please try it with it and pressing F9.

Comment: I have ran it as a script and have now got the following error: PL/SQL: ORA-00904: "CAPACITY": invalid identifier

Comment: Yes, because as stated before You do not have capacity column in tmpcapacityguide table. :) See my edit.

Answer (score 0):

`:new.capacity` is input and has to be declared. For more info see here: http://www.akadia.com/services/ora_bind_variables.html

Comment: This is trigger, and new and old are special cases of variables for triggers [read this](http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/triggers/before_update.php).